# Is there a way to include a subset of lines from an included file using m4?

Tags: m4

Is there a way to include a subset of lines from an included file when using m4? something along the lines of `` include(`source.cpp', 12-15)? ``

I'm creating a markdown presentation using reveal.js and want to include code samples. In many cases I want to include a subset of lines from a source file. In those cases I've created a copy of the file and trimmed each copy to what should be included at each inclusion. This however leads to multiple source files which need to be updated manually if a common line changes. I want to include the same file in multiple places, specifying which lines to include at each inclusion.

I've thought of using sed but want to avoid external tools if possible. I also want to be able to specify included folders using the m4 `-I` option.

Suggestions on m4 macros using external tools are welcome, even if an answer using m4 only is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can-do!

```
define(`repeat_newline',`ifelse($1,0,,`[^
]*
repeat_newline(decr($1))')')dnl
define(`quote',``$*'')dnl
define(`include_lines',`regexp(quote(include($1)),^repeat_newline($2)`\('repeat_newline($3)`\)',`\1')')
```

Usage: `include_lines(my_file.txt, 2, 5)` reads 5 lines starting from the third line (`2` is zero-indexed). It expands macros in the included file, just like `include`.

Answer (score 1):

> This however leads to multiple source files which need to be updated manually if a common line changes.

The main issue is how to insert the new version of a code sample (revision). That being said, you can insert *fixed text* calling an external command.

```
syscmd(`sed -n "12,15p" source.cpp')dnl
```

M4 rescans the inserted text after the expansion of the macro `include` whereas the text inserted calling `sed` is output literally (not parsed by M4).